# Cocoa: How do I know when a Controller is connected to a view? (Beginner)

Tags: macos, cocoa

I've attached a xib to a controller I made that inherits from NSObject.

I want to set a text field with dynamic text when the view is visible. How can I do that?

How can that controller know when it has access to a text field I want to populate?

Comment: [check this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15629515/is-there-a-simple-cocoa-application-tutorial-with-explanation/15629664#15629664)

Comment: That link doesn't tell me how I can know when a separate controller to the app delegate has access to the IBOutlet objects.

Comment: which controller? by default AppDelegate is the controller for all objects. Are you creating a new controller? in that case the outlets should be in `the` controller.

Comment: I've created a separate controller. The outlets are in the controller but what I want to know is how do I know when that controller has the IBOutlet values set. I see there's a method called `-viewDidLoad`. Can you shed any light on it?

Comment: viewDidLoad is the method will gets called when the view is loaded.  Actually I am not able to understand your real question...plz explain.

Comment: `- (void)awakeFromNib` was the method I was looking for.

Comment: OK good to know you get the answer by yourself :)

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look into the methods `-viewDidLoad` or `-nibDidLoad`.